# Windows 7 - Running Internet Explorer 9

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

I am working a in a bank and the key F12 in our bank's software inserts the last keyed-in account number. This was working fine, untill I installed Windows 7. Thereafter, whenever I hit F12 a developer tool box pop-up is coming and is disturbing my work-flow. I would like to know, is there anyway to change the default key assigned for "developer tools" ? Since IE 7 or any older version cannot be installed in Windows 7, can anybody suggest any solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

This link provides a method to disable the developer tools (since you're unlikely to need them): http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/152554-internet-explorer-f12-developer-tools-enable-disable.html

You may need to talk to IT since your local security policy probably won't let you modify much of the registry or change group policies. 
In fact, I'd suggest to IT that they make this a part of your group policy so all computers behave this way.

I'd *also* tell you to tell your developers that that's EXACTLY why you don't hijack function keys in JavaScript, but I'm sure they know that, now... :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like how this worked was something in the bank's software. It's possible that the bank software is/was just dumping the necessary info on to the clipboard and F12 was just mapped as a 'paste' shortcut (like ctrl+v generally is). Can you try using ctrl+v where you were using F12 before and see if that just "works" for you?

If that doesn't cut it, you'll need to find out how your bank's software was storing that last entered customer number. Or just teach people to copy and paste (ctrl+c and ctrl+v).